# Hard crash when playing media

Tags: upgrade, video, vlc, kodi

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from 15.10. Ever since the upgrade I am having problems playing video files in VLC and Kodi. Totem works fine.

The video will start playing but fairly quickly stops and freezes the entire system. Power cycling the machine seems to be the only way to get it back up and running again.

Initially I assumed something had gone wrong in the upgrade process, but after experiencing the exact same issue when running xubuntu 16.04 directly from dvd I suspect there most be a driver issue of some sort. I am at a lost on how to troubleshoot the issue.

I haven't had to do much troubleshooting over the last few years (thanks to a greatly improved product) so I'll need some hand holding on this one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
P

Answer (score 1):

Looking around, it appears to be that some people were able to solve this issue simply by using OpenGL. You can try changing Preferences -> Video -> Output and switching `Default` to `OpenGL`.

It would also be helpful if you posted the output of:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

so that we could know what GPU you're using.

You could also try installing graphics drivers (seeing as you're using the legacy AMD/ATI 4000 series) with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```

Comment: And if OpenGL doesn't work, try one of the "XCB" output options.

Comment: lspci output:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710 [Radeon HD 4350/4550]

Comment: I have updated my answer with some additional information that may help you.

Comment: I am having issues updating after adding the repository. Some missing packages.  I read some article about the fglrx drivers no longer being supported in ubuntu 16.04. I'll probably just install 15.10 until it's time for a new computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (HP EliteBook 840 G1) and it was related to the HDMI sound output on my hybrid graphic card (Even I had no external HDMI monitor connected).

And therefore I did what I already had done in previous ubuntu 14.04 release, I disabled HDMI sound output and only left PCH sound output:

1. Check the sound outputs:

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [HDMI_1         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xd0830000 irq 56
 1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xd0834000 irq 54
 2 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xd0540000 irq 55
```

2. Edit the file "**/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf**" and append the following:

```
...
options snd-hda-intel enable=0,1,0
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although I rely on HDMI output for sound. It has been working well for the last 7 or so years, but with the latest version of ubuntu that is no longer the case.